# TSQL turning rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table Items that has the following structure :

```
code  name     price    
001   item1    113      
002   item2    90      
003   item3    45        
004   item4    47
```

I need to make it that way :

```
code           001         002        003           004  
name           item1       item2      item3         item4
price          113         90         45             47
```

How can i achieve this please ?

Comment: In T-SQL? Don't. Use your presentation layer. You're mixing data types there, so it's even more ill-advised to do in your data engine.

Comment: It's a query that will be called from a stored procedure there is no application behind

Comment: _It's a simple query_, show us what did you try.

Comment: If it's being called from an SP, and an application isn't calling it, what is..?

Comment: it will be called directly from SSMS

Comment: And then what happens? *If nothing happens after that, what does formatting matter? You aren't doing anything with the data.*

Comment: @Larnu What happen next is _Comming Soon_

Comment: Sending to our ERP which does not support formating

Comment: So, if it doesn't support formatting, it doesn't matter how you send it. :) (Quite an impressive tool, most tools require specific formats, or expect one).

Comment: How is this data getting to your ERP? It doesn't "automagically" get there after you run the SP. You're missing steps here.

Comment: i mean by formating, formating the structure of data not the data itself, the way the SP runs in SSMS the way it will be displayed in our ERP.

Comment: So this ERP is running the SP, not SSMS? You said there wasn't an application running it earlier.

Comment: Yes effectively.

Comment: I'm really confused now. This completely contradicts what you said either, which is that *someone* runs the query in SSMS. Now you're saying that your ERP appcication is calling the SP. Which is it? If the latter, then you need to look at the changing the way your ERP reads the data.

Comment: do not care about erp, the way data is displayed in SSMS, is the way it will be displayed in ERP.

Comment: So, how is it getting from SSMS to the ERP? Like I said before, there's a step missing.

Comment: Is the count of rows (`code` values which will be columns afterwards) fixed / limited? Are these codes a gapless list from 1 to x in any case? If your ERP. What about *the way the SP runs in SSMS the way it will be displayed in our ERP*? The **grid** output in SSMS is a formatted display. As **text** output (simple copy and paste), you'd have to do some kind of padding and use a *fixed-width* font like *Courier New*... Many open questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `PIVOT` and `UNION`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (code VARCHAR(10),  name VARCHAR(10),    price INT)   
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('001','item1', 113),     
('002','item2', 90 ),    
('003','item3', 45 ),      
('004','item4', 47 ) 


SELECT header as code, [001], [002], [003], [004] FROM (
     SELECT 'name' header, code, name val FROM @MyTable  
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'price' header, code, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),price) val FROM @MyTable
 )SRC PIVOT( MAX(val) FOR code IN ( [001], [002], [003], [004])) PVT
```

Result:

```
code  001        002        003        004
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
name  item1      item2      item3      item4
price 113        90         45         47
```

Answer (score 0):

@zineddine reda, try with below query, you can do it using pivot feature provided by sql

```
declare @Tbl table (code varchar(50), name varchar(50), Price int)
insert into @Tbl values ('001', 'item1', 113)
insert into @Tbl values ('002', 'item2', 90)
insert into @Tbl values ('003', 'item3', 45)
insert into @Tbl values ('004', 'item4', 47)

declare @Tbl1 table (ItemNAme nvarchar(50), ItemVal nvarchar(50))
insert into @Tbl1 
  Select 'Code',  
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Code
        FROM @Tbl 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  
  from @Tbl
insert into @Tbl1 
  select 'Name', 
         STUFF((SELECT ', ' + name
         FROM @Tbl 
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
   from @Tbl
insert into @Tbl1 
   select 'Price', 
          STUFF((SELECT ', ' +  Convert(nvarchar(50),Price)
          FROM @Tbl 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
    from @Tbl

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Emp','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Emp

SELECT E.*, P.Value AS ItemValue, 'ItemValue' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),P.ID) AS ItemValueID, P.ID AS ID
INTO #Emp
FROM @Tbl1 E OUTER APPLY dbo.fnSplit1(E.ItemVal,',') P
DECLARE @MaxID INT, @Cols VARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @i INT
SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID) FROM #Emp 
SET @i = 1
SET @Cols = ''
WHILE @i <=@MaxID
   BEGIN
      SET @Cols = @Cols + ', [ItemValue' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @i) + ']'
      SET @i = @i + 1
   END
SET @Cols = RIGHT(@Cols, LEN(@Cols)-2)
print @Cols
SELECT @SQL = 'select ItemNAme, ' + @Cols + ' 
FROM (select ItemNAme, ItemVal, ItemValue, ItemValueID from #Emp) src
PIVOT (max(ItemValue) for ItemValueID IN (' + @Cols + '))pvt'
PRINT @SQL

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

and your fnSplit1 function will be

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit1]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
   While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
   Begin 
       Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
       Select
       Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
       Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
   End 

   Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
   Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
   Return
END
```

Comment: I'd suggest to Google for split functions. Yours is awfully outdated